# This widget created more than 20 pages. This may be an issue in the widget document in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf

I tried many ways like adding for loop, maxPages and adding in a ListView. I am not able to solve it. My code is below

I have referred many page still didn't get answer please help
My data is like this
{"City":{"Venkatesh":{"products":["Eenadu"]},"Jacob":{"products":["Times of India"]},"Sunita Menon":{"products":["Times of India","Malayala Manorama (Malabar)"]},"Keshav":{"products":["Times of India"]},"Anamika":{"products":["Times of India","Aalayam"]},"Kunal":{"products":["Aalayam","Economic Times","Times of India","Autocar"]},"Ferns City Residential Club":{"products":["Udaya Vani","Deccan Herald","Hindu"]},"Ashish":{"products":["Times of India"]},"Abraham":{"products":["Malayala Manorama (Kottayam)","Times of India"]},"K.K.":{"products":["Times of India"]},"SRIDHAR":{"products":["Deccan Herald"]},"Reji":{"products":["Deccan Herald","Times of India"]},"Sanjeev":{"products":["Times of India"]},"Sridhar":{"products":["Times of India"]},"Chetan":{"products":["Times of India"]},"nandish":{"products":["Times of India","Praja Vani"]},"Praveen":{"products":["Times of India","Sakshi"]},"Biju":{"products":["Deccan Herald","Malayala Manorama (Malabar)"]},"S. Senthil Kumar":{"products":["Times of India"]},"Sug...

```
static Future<Uint8List> generate(
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> subscriptionDetail,
  Map<String, dynamic> merchantDetails,
  String storeName) async {
final pdf = Document();

final font = await PdfGoogleFonts.nunitoExtraLight();
final ByteData _bytes =
    await rootBundle.load('assets/images/logozopnotepdf.png');
final Uint8List logobytes = _bytes.buffer.asUint8List();
List<pw.Widget> widgets = [];
print('Hello how ');
print(subscriptionDetail.length);
for (int i = 0; i < subscriptionDetail.length; i++) {
  widgets.add(buildReport(subscriptionDetail));
}
pdf.addPage(MultiPage(
  crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  header: (pw.Context context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        SizedBox(height: 1 * PdfPageFormat.cm),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            buildSupplierAddress(merchantDetails, logobytes, storeName),
            // Container(
            //   height: 50,
            //   width: 50,
            //   child:
            // ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 1 * PdfPageFormat.cm),
        Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            // buildCustomerAddress(invoice.customer),
            // buildInvoiceInfo(invoice.info),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
  build: (pw.Context context) => widgets,
  footer: (context) => buildFooter(),
));

return pdf.save();


}

  static Widget buildHeader(Map<String, dynamic> merchantDetail, Uint8List logo,
          String storeName) =>
      Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 1 * PdfPageFormat.cm),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              buildSupplierAddress(merchantDetail, logo, storeName),
              // Container(
              //   height: 50,
              //   width: 50,
              //   child:
              // ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 1 * PdfPageFormat.cm),
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              // buildCustomerAddress(invoice.customer),
              // buildInvoiceInfo(invoice.info),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      );
  static Widget buildSupplierAddress(Map<String, dynamic> merchantDetail,
          Uint8List logoImage, String storeName) =>
      Row(children: [
        Container(
            height: 120, width: 120, child: Image(MemoryImage(logoImage))),
        SizedBox(width: 20),
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('${storeName}',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20)),
            SizedBox(height: 1 * PdfPageFormat.mm),
            Text(
                '${merchantDetail['merchantAddress']['city']} \n${merchantDetail['merchantAddress']['street']}',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16)),
          ],
        )
      ]);
  static Widget buildReport(List<Map<String, dynamic>> subscriptionDetails) =>
      Column(
        children: [
          ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Column(children: [
                  Text('Route : ${subscriptionDetails[index].keys.first}'),
                  Text(subscriptionDetails[index].values.first.toString())
                ]);
              },
              itemCount: subscriptionDetails.length)
        ],
      );
```